# Loading data from Google Sheets into BigQuery using the bq command-line

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I would like to upload data from Google Sheets into Big Query using the bq CLI. This is currently possible via the could console web UI. But I could not find any relevant documentation on how to do it with bq command-line.

Comment: Why don't you directly the BQ data into Sheet, without an export with a bq cli?

Comment: Thanks @guillaumeblaquiere! But i'm looking for a cli match instead of a workaround or a better approach.

Comment: Therefore, you can't. It's mentioned in the limitation. First bullet point
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#export_limitations

Comment: I aware of that. I need to import into BQ, not to export.

Comment: Are you aware that isn't an import, but an external table creation? Did you try to create an external table with bq cli?

Comment: I agree, you indeed need to use an external table to [query drive data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive).